# Build Android on Jenkins failed due to licenses

Tags: android, jenkins

I have an app which is built with success when I use command assemble, etc... Everything works fine. I decided to use Jenkins, but I have an error on build which says :

```
* What went wrong:
25  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
26  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
27    [Android SDK Build-Tools 25].
28    Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
```

I'm using build tools version 25.0.0, and I updated SDK with last version on Jenkins with command `android update sdk --no-ui --filter the_index_to_update`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: Try typing android update sdk --no-ui --filter the_index_to_update --accept-license

Comment: using --accept-license doesn't work: Error: Flag '--accept-license' is not valid for 'update sdk'

Comment: Maybe drop the update sdk and try: android --accept-license

Comment: I just tried "android --accept-license" and same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Google says here: [Auto-download missing packages with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle)

You can copy your local license to the remote. So now it's working, just too bad for me to not know how to do when updating sdk on the remote...