# License not accepted for Android Build tools 26.0.2

Tags: android, jenkins, build-tools

I uploaded a new project to Jenkins that has compileSdkVersion as 26 and targetSdkVersion 25. I have accepted all licenses for the sdk with the below command:

```
 ./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Everything runs all good on my PC, but when I build on Jenkins it throws below error:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
Configuration 'testCompile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use'testImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'provided' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'compileOnly' instead.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in 
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/licenses

Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not 
accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 26 in 
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 26 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK 
components:
 [Android SDK Platform 26, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
```

I ran the same command to accept licenses on the Jenkins machine, and it said all the licenses have been accepted. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306201/build-android-on-jenkins-failed-due-to-licenses

Comment: @LalitVerma: I tried all that is mentioned in the link you mentioned as duplicate but it didnt work and hence I posted this question. There are many links and I tried almost all possible options from it. even ./sdkmanager --update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. The actual problem was that the local.properties file was missing which had the android sdk path

Answer (score 2):

Probably you accepted the licenses for the SDK APIs but the Build Tools are in the second tab. Open it from Android Studio and make sure you cover all the tabs, not just the first one.

To find the SDK Manager from AS go to File, Settings, Appereance & Behavior, System Settings, Android SDK. Check the second tab that says SDK Tools.

Comment: how can I do that from Android studio ?

Comment: you mean to download the "Google Play Licensing Library" right ?

Comment: No, í meant that maybe you forgot some build tools there. Is your version selected? Try to reinstall it from there if you do

Comment: Wait. Now that I think of. You don't have two sdk installations right? Maybe you accepted your user license but Jenkins i think has a way to download its own sdk

Comment: No, thats not the case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160051/discussion-between-sneha-and-sfratini).

Answer (score -1):

I believe your target SDK also should be 26

Comment: why do you believe this?, warning is something else